# How to iterate/ loop through a large (>2GB) JSON dataset in R/ Python?

Tags: python, json, r, bigdata

I was trying to do some exploratory analyses on a large (2.7 GB) JSON dataset using R, however, the file doesn't even load in the first place. When looking for solutions, I saw that I could process the data in smaller chunks, namely by iterating through the larger file or by down-sampling it. But I'm not really sure how to do that with a JSON dataset. I also thought of converting the original JSON data into .csv, but after having a look around that option didn't look that helpful.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Are you attempting to load the entire file into memory? And **then** explore it?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yep, that's what I did

Comment: I don't know R, really, but I might suggest you look into Apache Spark. https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/02/an-introduction-to-json-support-in-spark-sql.html

Comment: Pandas should be able to read JSON files. Haven't tried a large file, though

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks! I have zero experience with SQL, but it looks helpful though.

Comment: @cricket_007 I think I'll give it a go with pandas.

Comment: Dask might be better than Pandas for large datasets. http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/use-cases.html#json-data

Answer (score 1):

The `jsonlite` R package supports streaming your data. In that way there is no need to read all the json data into memory. See the documentation of `jsonlite` for more details, the `stream_in` function in particular.

---

Alternatively:

I would dump the json into a mongo database and process the data from that. You need to install mongodb, and start running mongod. After that you can use `mongoimport` to import the json file into the database.

After that, you can use the `mongolite` package to read data from the database.

Comment: I'll certainly try that out, thanks.

Comment: A full database installation might be overkill depending on the need for persistence or using the built-in query functions that it provides.

Comment: @cricket_007 You are right, although getting mongo running is not that hard. I added an alternative that uses streaming processing. That is probably even easier than using a mongodb as the stream already takes care of all the reading in chunks automatically.

Comment: Running mongo in docker wouldn't be hard, no :) I'm just saying seems like a hammer

Comment: I agree, `jsonlite` allows you to stream json, which is a much more lightweight solution.

Comment: I'll have a look at jsonlite (I was using rjson before). I'll let you know if it works. Should solve my problem, though.

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra Update: I've tried using the `stream_in` function. It does work for a while but R eventually crashes after some time. Would this be due to processing issues or problems with the actual data?

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question with a reproducible example of this issue. Than people can help you out.